# How to change iframe src when click date in calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup-balloons

I use `jquery balloon` to show `iframe` when I click `date` in `my calendar`.
Here is the link for [jquery balloon](http://urin.github.io/jquery.balloon.js/)
I want to get the clicked `date` and `send` it through `url` in `iframe`.
So I can use it using `$_GET`
But I have a lot of difficulties
Here's my `code`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var shown = true;
  $(function() {
  $.balloon.defaults.classname = "my-balloon";
  $.balloon.defaults.css = null;
    $('.date').on("click", function() {
      if (shown) {
        $('.date').hideBalloon();
        $(this).showBalloon();
        // Get text from what I click and used it in iframe src
        document.getElementById('iframe-date').src += '&date=' + $(this).text()
        shown = false;
      } else {
        $('.date').hideBalloon();
        shown = true;
      }
    }).showBalloon({
      //iframe is on contents
      contents: '<div style="text-align:right">'
        + '<img style="width:15px" onclick="closeBalloon()" src="<?php echo get_uri('public/images/icon-error.png') ?>">'
        + '</div>'
        + '<iframe id="iframe-date" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="<?php echo get_uri('admin/room/iframeDate/?id=' . $id) ?>"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>'
    });

    $('.date').hideBalloon();
  }); 

  function closeBalloon()
  {
    $('.date').hideBalloon();
    shown = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you are defining `iframe-date` in showballoon contents as string. It doesn't exist in the dome. I think that's the problem.

Comment: then what should I do? is there another way? because I need to send the data of what I click.

Comment: try creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code and give the link in your question.